# Some Textviews show wrong color when using gradle to build an Android App

Tags: android, build, gradle, textview

I want to use gradle to help me build Android APKs. When I build app with Intellij, everything goes fine but the gradle builds the `TextView` shows a color which like pink.

Even in the code using `setTextColor(R.color.gray)` will get this result. The only way I can change is to use `setTextColor(Color.GRAY)` but for that way, I can hardly use custom color. I don't know why.

```
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/stationName_item"
      android:layout_width="16dp"
      android:textSize="16sp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
      android:textColor="@color/gray" 
      android:gravity="center"/>
```

The color which I really want

[image: The color which I really want]

The color I get from gradle

[image: The color I get from gradle]

The first picture is what I want and the second picture is what I get from gradle.
It should show like this
And my main project's build.gradle is like:

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven {
            url "http://maven.oschina.net/content/groups/public"
           }
        }
        dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
        }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
        compileSdkVersion 18
        buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

        dependencies {
                compile project(":lib/actionbarsherlock")
                compile project(":lib/library")
                compile project(":lib/library1")
                compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        }


    sourceSets {
    main {
    manifest {
    srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    java {
    srcDir 'src'
    }
    res {
    srcDir 'res'
    }   
    assets {
    srcDir 'assets'
    }
    resources {
    srcDir 'src'
    }
    aidl {
    srcDir 'src'
    }
    }

    }
}
tasks.withType(Compile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
task copyNativeLibs(type: Copy) {
   from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so' )  into  'build/native-libs' 
}

tasks.withType(Compile) { compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn copyNativeLibs }

clean.dependsOn 'cleanCopyNativeLibs'

tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask -> 
     pkgTask.jniDir file('build/native-libs') 
}
```

Comment: can you show screenshots of color change.?

Comment: @SilentKiller Thank you,and I edit the question which already shows the screenshots

Comment: Well, to understand the behavior of Gradle we need to have the architecture of your project. Do you use libraries ? is your gray color in your "main" module ? is it overrided somewhere ?

Comment: @Andros Yes,the gray color in define in my "main" module.And the project libraries which I use not have the same color item name

Comment: What is the value of your gray color ? Do you specify your sourceSets in your build.gradle file ?

Comment: @Andros My value of gray is "#676767",I think it's fine as it shows fine without gradle.I edit the question which already show the main project's build.gradle. I sincerely  appreciate for that

Comment: can really see what is wrong here ... the only thing that could be wrong is if it's overrided somewhere. Or maybe Gradle keeped an old value of you resource. Have you tried to "gradle clean" your project ? When you click on your android:textColor="@color/gray" is it the correct color in your colors.xml file ?

Comment: Yeah,I tried to use "gradle clean" at first, but nothing happens.The result is also this way.And I'm sure the color is the correct color.And I searched all the project to find a item which named "gray",nothing overrided I could find.So,too confusing..